# How do I make a dysprosium chloride solution from dysprosium oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, experimental-chemistry, rare-earth-elements

I know that dysprosium oxide is insoluble in water.

I was told that I need to add concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ to the compound and then evaporate the $\ce{HCl}$ off. From looking at the reaction equation, I can see that I will get dysprosium chloride and water as products.

Once I'm able to dissolve the $\ce{Dy2O3}$, how is it that I'm supposed to evaporate off the excess $\ce{HCl}$? Do I just let it sit, or do I need to gently heat the solution? How can I tell when all the excess $\ce{HCl}$ is gone and I can start adding water to obtain the concentration of dysprosium chloride that I need?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].
I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Please do not use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 2):

DyCl3 is often prepared by the "ammonium chloride route," starting from either Dy2O3 or hydrated chloride or oxychloride.[2][3] or DyCl3·6H2O.[4] These methods produce (NH4)2[DyCl5]:

```
    10 NH4Cl + Dy2O3 → 2 (NH4)2[DyCl5] + 6 NH3 + 3 H2O

    DyCl3·6H2O + 2 NH4Cl → (NH4)2[DyCl5] + 6 H2O
```

The pentachloride decomposes thermally according to the following equation:

```
    (NH4)2[DyCl5] → 2 NH4Cl + DyCl3
```

The thermolysis reaction proceeds via the intermediacy of (NH4)[Dy2Cl7].

Treating Dy2O3 with aqueous HCl produces hydrated chloride (DyCl3·6H2O). This salt cannot be rendered anhydrous by heating. Instead one obtains an oxychloride.

source: wikipedia